# error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'. (NgRx)

Tags: ngrx

I have an error in my project and i can't find where is the problem.
I see in my NGRX dev tool that the action is fired and get the state updared with the new data, but I get this error in the console and it bothers me.

This is my state:

```
export interface User {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

action:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

export const loaduser = createAction(
  '[USER] Load',
  props<User>()
);
```

reducer:

```
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import * as UserAction from '../actions/user.actions';
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

export const initialState: User = null;

const commentReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(UserAction.loaduser, (state, payload) =>  payload)
);

export function reducer(state: User, action: Action) {
  return commentReducer(state, action);
}
```

component with api:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.store.dispatch(loaduser(data));
    });
  }
```

Comment: You should checkout https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app/src/app . what you're specifically looking for is how to implement effects. Your service calls should be done there

Answer (score 0):

Your`userService` getUsers method probably doesn't have proper return type set (should be `Observable<User>`) so the subscription assumes the response is unknown Object which you are then trying to pass as a parameter of type `User`.

This should fix it:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data: User) => {
      this.store.dispatch(loaduser(data));
    });
  }
```

Note the type on `data` param. But you should also make sure the service is properly typed as well.